# Import Python module 'NameError: name 'contact' is not defined' error

Tags: python, import, module

I'm going to connect to mysql using Python.

Attempt to create a module file named dbconn.py and import the dbconn module for mysql connection.

However, an error occurs when the variable is not found.

Help me.

```
# dbconn.py
import pymysql

def contact():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='test', password='test', db='test', charset='utf8')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = 'SELECT mail_addr FROM contact'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    contact = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
```

```
# mail.py
import dbconn

dbconn.contact

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('abcd@gmail.com', 'abcd')
sender = 'abcd@gmail.com'

for i in contact:
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = 'test'
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = i[0]
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    smtp.sendmail(sender, i[0], msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: You're trying to iterate over `contact`. But contact hasn't been defined in your `mail.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that your "contact" function needs to

```
   return contact
```

and then the call on mail.py has to be:

```
   contact = dbconn.contact()
```

to create the list you want to iterate on.